# Mapbox Mobile Unscaled Map

Tags: mobile, mapbox

New to maps and would like to make a map from scratch. Can Mapbox do this for mobile applications?  If not, is there another tool that would work?

Here is a list of the requirements:

- Map must work on mobile devices running iOS and Android.
- Map is on local device and can't require a server connection.
- Map is semi-fictional. Represents a real place but not to any standard or consistent scale (ex. London Underground Map)
- Support multiple zoom levels.
- Show inside of multi-story buildings when zoomed.
- Allow paths and points to be defined.

Soft requirements:

- Small memory footprint
- Well supported and stable platform

Nice to have

- Uses open standards.
- Free to use.

Thx

Comment: not sure what you mean by 'has no scale', but Yes, mapbox/leaflet can be used for mobile apps

Comment: I've been working on the right terms to use. In this case, "no scale" means something like a ski resort map. The runs on the map are not to any particular scale. It is a more stylized map.

Comment: It says it works for web maps, not mobile. I need my map to available offline. I won't have a web browser available either.

Comment: i've used mapbox for mobile apps, but we did require internet connectivity for the basemap tiles.  if you're not using a tile service for any of your layers, it might work just fine offline.

Answer (score 0):

Okay - so assuming that unscaled means non-georeferenced, yes: you can [use your image as a source in TileMill](http://www.macwright.org/2012/08/13/images-as-maps.html), export to MBTiles, and use the result in the [Mapbox iOS SDK](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-ios-sdk/) and [Mapbox Android SDK](https://www.mapbox.com/blog/mapbox-android) offline.

Comment: Some points of interest are at known locations. Not sure what non-georeferenced means, but I would say it is georeferenced at those known points. Again, think London Underground map. Stations have known locations and there are paths between stations, but distances have no consistent scale.